# find list of running activity

Tags: android

There are 6 activities in my application .

I start new activity when click menu item even if same activity started previously .
There is no need to start new activity.

How can i get that running previously activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` declare your activity as `SingleInstace`

(Application->Activity->Launch mode->SingleInstance).

If your activity is running then it doesn't create a new one.

Comment: @carlow: Google does not recommend this. Very few applications need `singleInstance` -- a home screen is the only one I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `android:launchMode` here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode. `"singleTop"` is probably what you want.

Note that the default behavior is the way it is to make the back button work automatically.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Now works fine. Thanks for your help.What is defference in "singleTop" and "SingleInstance" ??

Answer (score 1):

> How can i get that running previously activity ?? and run it ??

Add `FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT` on the `Intent` you use with `startActivity()`.

Comment: @Nandlal Virani: Call `setFlags()` on the `Intent`, passing in `FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. Then, pass that `Intent` to `startActivity()`.